# Regarding the behavior of C double type

Tags: c

I executed the following snippet of code (compiled using gcc)

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    double b = 5 % 3 & 4 + 5 * 6;
    printf("%lf", b);
}
```

The output is 2.000000
I am not getting the reason why it is so.

Comment: what value are you expecting?

Comment: ... and why are you expecting that value?

Comment: Have you ever heard of precedence?

Comment: 30.000000?? how you evaluate it?

Comment: Try `gcc -Wall` next time

Answer (score 6):

Bitwise `&` has lower [precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) than `*`, `%`, `+`.  Operands will be grouped as

```
 double b = (5 % 3) & (4 + 5 * 6);
```

`5%3` = 2 =  `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010`
`34`  = `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 0010`
Bit-wise ANDing both yield `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010`  = 2

Comment: somebody downvoted me, too. i didn't downvoted you, but i think you're giving too much effort and that might draw reaction sometimes. I prefer giving just what is requested now after I got the same reaction.

Comment: @IsmetAlkan What you said makes sense, however everything I included is useful to the OP - Explains how to get expected output, and why the original code was giving the unexpected output.

Answer (score 3):

To get your expected output of `30.000000` you have to specify the order of operations - you could use parens.  You need to tell the compiler that you want the `AND` to happen directly after the `5 % 3`.

```
double b = (5 % 3 & 4) + 5 * 6; // Specify precedence
```

Output: `30.000000`

---

Your original code executes in this precedence.

```
double b = (5 % 3) & (4 + (5 * 6)); // Added parens to show how it executes
```

Output: `2.000000`

Basically, you were `AND`ing (5 % 3) with (4 + (5 * 6)).

Comment: Why the down vote?  Would be helpful to me and the OP if an explanation was provided.

Comment: You should not expect something from coward people. I named them "Ghost Soul"

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused because of the bitwise-And (&) operator.

It might seem unintuitive, but it has a **lower precedence** than multiplication, addition and modulus operations.

This was considered an "*infelicity of C's precedence rules*" by Dennis Ritchie but was nevertheless accepted into the language.

You can find Ritchie's exposition on this, among other matters here: http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/chist.html

Answer (score 0):

`&` has lower precedence than you think. You can check them all [here](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm).